# GeoKettle and scheduling transformations / jobs?

Tags: coordinate-system, iteration, geokettle, tasks

Is there any possibility to schedule a transformation or job with GeoKettle?

I would like to perform the same task every day.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is possible, by using Spoon, you can view the steps [here](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0L0/0Y0/0J0/000). In short, you will be able to set the task up for transformation and create a schedule to automate the tasks. Here are some visuals of the steps provided. I would imagine similar method may employed to work with GeoKettle.

[image]

In the Schedule a Transformation dialog box, enter the date and time that you want the schedule to begin in the Start area, or click the calendar icon (circled in red) to display the calendar. To run the transformation immediately, enable the Now radio button.

[image]

Set up the End date and time. If applicable, enable the No end radio button or click on the calendar and input the date and time to end the transformation.

If applicable, set up a recurrence under Repeat.

End date and time are disabled unless you select a recurrence. From the list of schedule options select the choice that is most appropriate: Run Once, Seconds, Minutes, Hourly, Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Yearly.

Make sure you set parameters, arguments and variables, if available. Click OK.
In the Spoon button bar, click the Schedule perspective.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i was hoping for a possibility like in spoon for kettle.
Although i have a spoon.bat after the installation of GeoKettle, but when i run it a different GUI starts:
[Valid XHTML](http://sogeo.ch/images/fun_with_geokettle_ep2/geokettle_diff_dtm_av.png).
And this GUI is missing the "Actions" and "Scheduling"- buttons...

Or can i maybe use the Spoon from Kettle to run GeoKettle transformations?

Comment: Yes, that would be my recommendation, I think if you use Spoon that would work just as well.

Comment: Hmmm, i seem to be too stupid to properly link an image here. But please follow the link in the above comment to see what my GUI looks like when i start spoon.bat

Comment: Yes, I see that image in the above comment, you are missing those buttons, that's odd. I'm not exactly sure why that is the case. Perhaps a bug or some issue during installation, possibly.

Comment: I'm beginning to fear that the schduling of a task is simply not yet implemnted in GeoKettle as it is in Kettle, as all the screenshots in the GeoKettle-documentation dont show the "actions"-button too.
I just installed Kettle and tried to open my GeoKettle-transformation. But of course it does not know the spatial-related steps from GeoKettle...